# Java+MongoDB hosting

Tags: java, mongodb, cloud-hosting, mongodb-java

I have a mobile app for which I need a java/mongodb support in the Backend. I am thinking of various combos to use. I dont wanna spend a lot of money to begin with as its just a 'hobby' app, for now.

These are the various options I have thought of:

Host Java and MogoDB on EC2 -> Ill have to manage all mongoDB admin work from creating replica sets to backups (m not a mongo DB guru)

Host Java someplace (any suggestions ?) and MongoDB on mongolab.com or mongohq.com -> they manage mongodb for me and i just write the Java layer and just work on my DB design.

Any inputs on a cheap option out there  ?

Comment: There are backend services like netmera (http://netmera.com) that does every backend work for you. as far as i know, they use mongodb. you may use it

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you try [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com). It supports a lot of addons, including MongoLab. I have an application hosted there, using one dyno*, and it's fully free.

If you want try a simple java app, using mongodb as storage system, take a look here:
https://github.com/cartagena/heroku-vraptor-mongodb

> A dyno, the basic unit of composition on Heroku, is a lightweight
>   container running a single user-specified command.

Comment: Not sure if Asker implied java webapp or a java process, if we have to host java webapp, do you still recommend Heroku? Heroku has way to deploy war on tomcat but it doesn't provide much options of configuring tomcat to your liking: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner

Comment: Yep. It is indeed free.  And their Clojure support is amazing!

Comment: MongoLab was sold and You have to provide some security id of Your private cloud space to connect with it and heroku price is high if You want to have private space

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using MongoDB as a service from ObjectRocket. The service takes care of many of the administrative taks for running Mongo and you can leave your Java app where it is today.